# In Windows what is a "runtime image"?

Tags: windows, terminology

I am reading the book "MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide".

On page 362 it states:

---

• mysql-debug contains support for debugging.  Normally, you don't choose this server for production use because it has a larger runtime **image** and uses more memory.

---

What is an "image"?  I have searched extensively to try to find the answer.

Comment: Perfectly fine and reasonable question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image is the size of the executable code in memory.

In general, "X uses more memory than Y" could refer to both the runtime image size and the amount of space allocated for non-executable data.  This quotation is clarifying that *both* are worse in the debug version.